# git pull gives error: 401 Authorization Required while accessing https://git.foo.com/bar.git

Tags: git

My macbook pro is able to clone/push/pull from the company git server.
My cent 6.3 vm gets a 401 error

```
git clone https://git.acme.com/git/torque-setup
"error: The requested URL returned error: 401 Authorization Required while accessing https://git.acme.com/git/torque-setup/info/refs
```

As a work around, I've tried creating a folder, with an empty repository, then setting the remote to the company server. I get the same error when trying a git pull

The remotes are identical between the machines

***MacBook Pro*** (working)

```
git --version
git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)

git remote -v
origin  https://git.acme.com/git/torque-setup (fetch)
origin  https://git.acme.com/git/torque-setup (push)
```

***Cent 6.3*** (not working)

```
yum install -y git

git --version
git version 1.7.1

git remote -v
origin  https://git.acme.com/git/torque-setup (fetch)
origin  https://git.acme.com/git/torque-setup (push)
```

The git server only allows https. Not git or ssh connections.

Why is the  macbook pro able to do a git pull, while the cent os machine can't?

***Solution Update 2013-5-15***

As jku mentioned, the culprit is the old version of git installed on the cent box. Unfortunately, 1.7.1 is what you get when you run `yum install git`

The work around is to manually install a newer version of git, or simply add the username to the repo

```
git clone https://joe@git.acme.com/git/torque-setup
```

Comment: Added user to gitrepo link, e.g. https://[user]@git.acme.com/git/torque-setup works. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would update the git version: 1.7.10 (or thereabouts) had authentication improvements. It's possible that these improvements were only related to proxies though -- I've forgotten the details already.

Speaking of proxies, you could double-check git config: You wouldn't have proxies or anything like that configured on the macbook but not on the cent machine?

Comment: That was it. The version of git that comes in the cent base repository, requires that the username be explicitly stated. I'll add the work around to the description.

Comment: I had a similar issue and found that 1.7.9 worked OK as well.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing 
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

To fix it, I did the following:

```
check git version: 1.7.1
update git
```