# How to update git version in Godaddy Share hosting?

Tags: git, laravel, gitlab

In my share hosting git version is **1.7.1**

I want to clone my project from **Gitlab**, but every time it failed.

> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/qk5k59gyivcv/ytfbposts/.git/
>   error: The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized while
>   accessing https://gitlab.com/suonsamoun/ytfbposts.git/info/refs

I search for the solution and here [git pull gives error: 401 Authorization Required while accessing https://git.foo.com/bar.git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572286/git-pull-gives-error-401-authorization-required-while-accessing-https-git-foo) said that it because of git version. Can u pleae tell me how to update git to the latest version?

I have tried to follow this instruction https://www.godaddy.com/help/install-git-on-my-web-and-classic-hosting-account-12391 but it still show version **1.7.1**

Comment: I also have the same problem. I'm trying to install NVM, which requires at least git 1.7.10, but my Godaddy's Linux server has git 1.7.1 installed. Did you find a solution?